# How can I increase ArcMap font size, I can barely read it!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, windows-8, font, accessibility

I'm sure there is a simple answer out there, but how do I increase the font size in the ArcMap work windows?  I am using Windows 8 on a Surface tablet.

Comment: You might look at this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/make-text-screen-larger-smaller/?v=t  The short answer from Microsoft is to use 8.1 update.  The problem in scaling is that a change that may make the text or icons larger may also make some dialog or form boxes hard to use.

Answer (score 7):

ArcMap respects the default font size of the operating system. You can change the font size in your control panel. You can also [turn on magnification](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/get-best-display-monitor) to make all "Classic" Windows apps larger and more readable.

Comment: ArcMap 10.3.1.4959, the Identify Dialog box is not abiding by this rule.  I have to use my phone's camera to zoom in on it to see the values.  The font size of Identify would be adequate if I could find my reading glasses.  But having flexible font sizes in modern software applications is the reason I have been able to postpone getting another pair of glasses.

Answer (score 1):

You can change font size of **tables** in ArcMap: Customize/ArcMap Options/Tables tab.  CHange font type and size, cell ht, etc.

However, I also have my settings in Windows 7 set at 125%: control panel/display/click radio button by 'medium - 125%.  I have no idea if it works the same in 8.

Same with internet browser - lower right corner to change to 125%'.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue!
I solved it by increasing TEXT ONLY in windows>

Try: Windows Start Button -> 'Ease of Access Display Settings' -> Make Text Bigger : increase slider to 120% - Voila!

article:
https://www.bing.com/search?q=change%20text%20size%20windows%2010%20site:microsoft.com&form=B00032&ocid=SettingsHAQ-BingIA&mkt=en-US&rdr=1&rdrig=416AF176A935490F979B48F941417D05

Also, in ArcMap v.10.3 U can easily increase text in Attribute Table simply by: Ctrl + Mouse scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard from ESRI that ArcGIS For Desktop scales poorly with high pixel density displays. It does not occur in ArcGIS Pro. We were having crashing problems with the application in an unrelated issue, but they said:

Agent: Using high resolutions like 4K on a small screen will result in ArcMap icons being very small.
Agent: That is how the application is made.

Agent: If the monitors are big enough (22 inches or more) then the resolution should not matter.

Agent.: The issue mostly occur on high resolution laptop displays and surface tablets.

Agent: One workaround is to reduce the resolution whenever ArcMap is being used.